# How to get the date of the month from the cookie?

Tags: autoit

First I make a request on google.com
Then I get the values.
And pull the date of the month.

```css
 $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
 $oHTTP.Open("GET", "https://google.com", False);    
 $oHTTP.Send();
 $HeaderResponses = $oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders();   cookie
 ;$resp=$oHTTP.ResponseText;                           html
 $date = StringRegExpReplace($HeaderResponses, '/^(?!.*$)(.*)$/', '/^(?!.*$)(.*)$/'); get date
 FileWriteLine("test.txt", $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will helpful or not I have used string functions for your query:

```
cpp
#include <StringConstants.au3>

$oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
$oHTTP.Open("GET", "https://google.com", False)
$oHTTP.Send()

$HeaderResponses = $oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders() ; cookie
;$resp = $oHTTP.ResponseText                      ; html

$datepostionstart = StringInStr($HeaderResponses,"Date:")
$datepostionstend = StringInStr($HeaderResponses,"GMT")
$firstsring       = StringLeft($HeaderResponses,$datepostionstend-10)

MsgBox(1,"",$firstsring)

$date = StringTrimLeft($firstsring,$datepostionstart+10)

MsgBox(1,"",$date)

FileWriteLine("test.txt", "Cookie Date = "&$date)
```